# IE dropdown menus behind pdf in iframe

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, iframe

I'm trying to fix a site where multiple pdfs are pulled into an iframe depending on the menu item you select. This works fine for most browsers but in IE7, 8 and 9 when a pdf is displayed in the iframe the dropdown nav goes behind the iframe.

This is not a z-index problem, I know it's an issue with IE. I also know that I can use google pdf view and all will be well but they don't want to rely on this.

Can anyone offer a suggestion on how to fix this. Is there a plugin I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this, I use an other iFrame.
I call this helperIframe, and place it behind the dropdown

You can see in the source of: http://neckermann.schmetterling-quadra.de/

Hope that helps.

```
<li rel="id:{$group.id}" onmouseover="showNaviPoints(Navi{$group.id})" onmouseout="hideNaviPoints(Navi{$group.id})"> ...
<ul ...>
</ul>   
<iframe id="helperIframe{$group.id}" style="display:none;"></iframe>

function showNaviPoints(navi)
{
    jQuery(navi).css('display', 'block').next().css({
        'display'   : 'block',
        'width'     : jQuery(navi).width(),
        'height'    : jQuery(navi).height(),
        'position'  : 'absolute',
        'border'    : 'none'

    });
}
function hideNaviPoints(navi)
{
    jQuery(navi).parent().parent().find('li ul').css('display', 'none');
    jQuery(navi).css('display', 'none').next().css('display', 'none');
}
```